# String interpolation in Typescript, replacing 'placeholders' with variables

Tags: angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I cannot seem to find a clear enough answer on this topic, so I am asking the question:

In C#, I can do the following, for instance:

```
var text = "blah blah";
var strTest = String.Format("This is a {0}", text); //output: 'This is a blah blah'
```

How would I achieve this in Typescript?

**Usage:**

I am loading a URL from the environment.ts file, and this string URL will need to contain the placeholders, and in my service layer, replace the placeholders with the actual parameters that needs to be passed in.

Comment: Is the `environments.ts` file contents controlled by you, or is it something external and forced to some particular format?

Comment: Controlled by me

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use a [template string](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/template-strings) which are much better than `String.Format` in my opinion as they do not suffer from poor indexing (wrong placeholder) issues:

```js
var text = "blah blah";
var strTest = `This is a ${text}`;
console.log(strTest);
```

> If I do not know the name of the variables I need to pass in??

Then wrap in a function e.g.

```
const gen = (text) => `This is a ${text}`;
```

Comment: I maybe should have given more context, sorry. I am loading a URL from the environment.ts file, and this string will need to contain the placeholders, and in my service layer, replace the placeholders with the actual parameters that needs to be passed in

Comment: I love the idea of wrapping formatting in a function that replacements are passed in to. Thanks for the tip, @basarat!

Answer (score 20):

I'd suggest using anonymous generator functions in your `environments.ts` file, so you could pass the variables you need and have the template strings inside this functions. Something like this:

environments.ts

```
 export const thisIsA = (str: string) => `This is a ${str}`;
```

Some other file:

```
import * as env from 'environments';

var text = "blah blah";
var strTest = env.thisIsA(text); //output: 'This is a blah blah'
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a npm package called [localized-strings](https://github.com/stefalda/localized-strings) it has a formatString method which can be used for string interpolation in a C# fashion.

```
import LocalizedStrings, {LocalizedStringsMethods} from "localized-strings";

interface IStrings extends LocalizedStringsMethods{
}

const localizedStrings: IStrings  = new LocalizedStrings({en: {}});
const result = localizedStrings.formatString("This is a {0}", "Text").toString();
console.log(result);
```

More examples [here](https://github.com/stefalda/localized-strings/blob/master/spec/LocalizedStrings.spec.js)

Answer (score -1):

In your enviornment.ts:

```
export const str = "This is a {0} and this is {1}.";
```

Use while runtime, anywhere:

```
import * as env from 'environments';

console.log(env.str.replace('{0}', 'blah blah').replace('{1}', 'again a blah blah'));
```

Comment: Which version of Angular is this?