# How can I replace string values in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, string

I currently have a string value as follows:

```
"{"rows":[{"columns":[{"styleClass":"col-md-3"},{"styleClass":"col-md-3"},{"styleClass":"col-md-3"},{"styleClass":"col-md-3"}]},{"columns":[{"styleClass":"col-md-6"},{"styleClass":"col-md-6"}]}]}"
```

How can I replace every styleClass keyword with Class to change it to:

```
"{"rows":[{"columns":[{"Class":"col-md-3"},{"Class":"col-md-3"},{"Class":"col-md-3"},{"Class":"col-md-3"}]},{"columns":[{"Class":"col-md-6"},{"Class":"col-md-6"}]}]}"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: .replace() and .replaceAll() don't seem to work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196421/string-interpolation-in-typescript-replacing-placeholders-with-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because u have duble quotes inside double quotes

```js
let incial = '{"rows":[{"columns":[{"styleClass":"col-md-3"},{"styleClass":"col-md-3"},{"styleClass":"col-md-3"},{"styleClass":"col-md-3"}]},{"columns":[{"styleClass":"col-md-6"},{"styleClass":"col-md-6"}]}]}';
let replaced = incial.replaceAll("styleClass","Class");
console.log(replaced);
```